# Partition data vs Data Source View

Tags: ssas, bids

Good day.

I would like to ask for some assistance/advise. I do not work too much with ssas cube development so please forgive me if i am asking stupid questions.

i have a particular cube that i would like to partition into individual years. i have one query in the DSV. I have created all the separate partitions into each individual years by restricting the data in the 'WHERE' clause of the sql query (which is the same query in the DSV).

i have created partitions for years 2015,2016,2017. i then restricted the data in the DSV to look at data from 2018 to current. This is where i seem to be getting stuck, is that the correct way to to create the partitions? After doing this now i only get calendar years for 2018 and 2019 in my Date/Time dimensions when pulling data into Excel. But when i browse this dimension inside of BIDS i see Calendars from 2009 to 2019.

i am not sure if i am correctly creating the partitions (probably not if i am not getting the desired results). i have a few questions if i may to try and help me understand a few things.

1. Do i have to restrict my DSV query as well to only look at data from 2018 to current if i have already restricted these values in my partitions or should my DSV have all data with no restrictions?
2. Do i need to have a partition for 2018 to current (that matches my DSV - same 'WHERE' restriction) as well as other partitions (2015,2016,2017)

I am using BIDS 2008.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to sort my issue and found answers to my questions by posting on the MS SQL forum. for anyone that may be interested can check this [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e5d50aae-8299-4676-8300-5152aeb70774/partition-data-vs-data-source-view?forum=sqlanalysisservices)